# Problem with Boolean -> Intersect

Tags: modifiers

Intersect should be the opposite of "Difference" but this does not work. My mash is invisible, when I use Intersect.
Difference works perfect, but I neet the other direction. What's wrong in my settings?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Boolean modifier* depends on the direction of the normal.

[image]

**But!** Citation from [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html):

> Only Manifold meshes are guaranteed to give proper results, other cases (especially “opened” meshes, Non-manifold but without any self-intersections) will usually work well, but might give odd glitches and artifacts in some cases.

That actually means that this result may be just lucky.

To use a *Boolean modifier* more safely, use a cube instead of a plane. You can create a cube tall enough to cover the entire volume of the object (cylinder) you want to cut out, and set the *Boolean* to either intersection or difference, either will work for you:

[image]

Comment: I honestly thought until now that the result of a boolean operation on objects where one or both are non-manifold cannot be guaranteed and can be highly unpredictable. This is kind of enlightening for me.

Comment: Ok, now I have another question regarding this Mod. My Mesh has a Material, when I cut it, with your methode, The cut part is white...do you know why? https://www.dropbox.com/s/teb30bp4251lbi9/Boolean.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Faces of the cut inherits materials from the other operant (mesh). 

Anyway if the answer answers your original question properly, please mark it as approved, if not, tell me what is unsatisfactory and I will update it accordingly.